# Every $2$-Forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as edge of $1$-Forms

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $\omega \in \text{Alt}^{2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ a $2$-Forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Show that it exists $\alpha, \beta \in \text{Alt}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that $\omega = \alpha \wedge \beta$.

Comment: If $\omega=Ady\wedge dz+Bdz\wedge dx+Cdx\wedge dy$ it may help the fact that for each integral over a surface $S$ we've $$\iint_{S}\omega=\iint_R \left(A\frac{J(y,z)}{J(v,w)}+B\frac{J(z,x)}{J(v,w)}+C\frac{J(x,y)}{J(v,w)}\right)dv\wedge dw$$ where $R$ is a region over the $v,w$-plane which is used to parameterize $S$

Comment: @janmarqz thanks for the advice, but unfortunately I didn't saw yet integral of a differential form over a region

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that every vector $w$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the vector product of two other vectors: $w = u\times v$.

Comment: You mean that the cross product can build a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$?